# Sum, Subtract and Join of multiple mysql table columns

Tags: mysql, join, sum, subtraction

I have four mysql tables `client`, `transaction`, `other_loan` and `payment`. I want to get the `sum` of `load_amount` and `additional` from table `transaction` + `sum` of `amount` from `other_loan` and `subtract` it to the `sum` of `payment_amount` in table `payment`. How can I achieve it?

> Result I want:

```
>  ID | Name     |  Amount
>  1  | Robin    | 8718  
>  2  | Reynaldo | 21
>  3  | Leomar   | 0
```

> My Tables:
>   transaction

```
>  tid | id| date       | load_amount | additional
>  1   | 1 | 2018-12-01 |    90       | 0  
>  2   | 1 | 2018-12-07 |    90       | 0
>  3   | 2 | 2018-12-08 |    49       | 2
```

> table: other_loan

```
> oid | id| amount   |  date
> 1   | 1 | 7928     | 2018-12-10
> 2   | 1 | 750      | 2018-12-10
```

> table: payment

```
> pid |id | payment_amount  | date
> 1   | 1 |      50         | 2015-12-10
> 2   | 1 |      90         | 2015-12-10
> 3   | 2 |      30         | 2015-12-10
```

> table: client

```
> id | Name       |  
> 1  | Robin      | 
> 2  | Cinderella |
> 3  | Leomar     |
```

Comment: Do the `id` values in `transaction`, `other_loan` and `payment` all refer to the `id` value in `client`?

Comment: Yes sir. That is correct. I can't get the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have multiple transactions, other loan amounts and payments per customer, you can't do a straight `JOIN` of the tables to each other as it will cause replication of rows, resulting in incorrect values. Instead, we `SUM` all the values within each table on a client basis *before* doing the `JOIN`. Additionally, since some clients don't have entries in each table, you must use `LEFT JOIN`s and `COALESCE` on the results so that empty rows don't cause SUMs to become `NULL`. This query should give you the results you want:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name,
       COALESCE(t.transactions, 0) + COALESCE(o.amounts, 0) - COALESCE(p.payments, 0) AS amount
FROM client c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, SUM(load_amount) + SUM(additional) AS transactions
           FROM transaction
           GROUP BY id) t on t.id = c.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, SUM(amount) AS amounts
           FROM other_loan
           GROUP BY id) o ON o.id = c.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, SUM(payment_amount) AS payments
           FROM payment
           GROUP BY id) p ON p.id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
id  name        amount
1   Robin       8718
2   Cinderella  21
3   Leomar      0
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf0b5d/5)

Comment: Thank you very much @Nick, it works. Thank you for your time and effort.